# Use cases for const HashMap/BTreeMap

Tags: rust, constants

The [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/constant-items.html) say:

> A constant item is an optionally named constant value which is not associated with a specific memory location in the program. Constants are essentially inlined wherever they are used, meaning that they are copied directly into the relevant context when used.

While that sounds perfectly reasonable for "simple" values like integers, booleans, etc., doesn't it also mean that for more complex/larger data structures, like `HashMap`/`BTreeMap`s, for example, consts can be quite inefficient? If so, why (in what situations) would one want to use consts for such structures, instead of, say, an immutable static variable?

Comment: You're also quite limited in how you can initialize consts, I believe even `HashMap::new()` won't do

Comment: You cannot create a `const MAP: HashMap<...>` because there's no `const fn` that can construct it. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1db26a5d76b21ea8d25b128b81c7f721) - *"calls in constants are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants"*

Comment: Expensive data structures like maps and vecs require calling the allocator. The allocator is not const, so anything that uses alloc cannot be const.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure about `HashMap`, but for `BTreeMap` apparently work is [in progress](https://caniuse.rs/features/const_btreemap_new) and it's already available in Nightly.

Comment: Oh cool! But I don't think that's particularly useful on it's own; you could create a `const MAP: BTreeMap<...>` but it'd always be empty. Useful in a generic sense perhaps, but that doesn't really fit the "complex/larger data structures" that you're asking about.

Comment: It is useful for `static`, in the same manner that `Vec::new()` is `const fn` and it helps initializing statics without the overhead of `once_cell` or `lazy_static`. Const allocations are possible, but are not something actively being worked on AFAIK. Though they have they own use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

> If so, why (in what situations) would one want to use consts for such structures, instead of, say, an immutable static variable?

Constant variables are, technically, the only way of getting an "immutable static variable" in Rust.

Other solutions, like `lazy_static`, require overhead in initializing the value and tracking whether it is initialized or not, or risk unsafety.

Constant values are embedded into the read-only data in the executable, like strings or the machine code. This is pretty much as efficient as normal memory - there isn't any overhead.

Another reason for `const` is for [constant generics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2000-const-generics.html).

Comment: You're confusing `const` and `static`. And I'll hardly advocate for const generics `HashMap`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Not really. Constants are effectively static - there's no need to have more than one instance of a particular const. And my answer has nothing to do with HashMap in particular.

Comment: The question was about `HashMap`. And `const`, as opposed to `static`, can (and does) copy-pasted for each use, and not necessarily embedded in the resulted binary at all.